# How to make a citation for a sentence that is used in my own context?

Tags: citation

I have read something from an author and I think I would like to use part of his idea in my own context. But how should I cite the author so that it isn't misleading? Let me give an example.

Suppose I have read this and wanted to use this idea from Dunne & Raby in my article:

> Critical design uses designed artifacts as an embodied critique or
>   commentary on consumer culture.

Since my article is written in my own context, I may end up using the sentence this way:

> The design of Product X is an embodied critique on the consumer culture.

Now, if I were cite Dunne & Raby:

> The design of Product X is an embodied critique on the consumer culture (Dunne & Raby, 1999).

This may appear as if Dunne & Raby said that Product X is an embodied critique on the consumer culture when they were actually commenting about something more general.

I can't put quotes either since I'm lifting it entirely from its original statement.

Would how I have cited the author correct in the form of APA citation? If not, how should I cite it so that it would be clearer?

Comment: To put it simply, you are not quoting anyone, so you won't be 'citing' anything. If you find a sentence structure suitable to your context, you may use it -- I don't think you need to acknowledge 'inspiration' from another source for that. *Remember **never to change anything**, not even punctuation, if you claim to quote someone.* -- Quote exactly or don't quote at all.

Comment: Better to ask questions of this type on writersSE. They're OT on ELU.

Comment: According to Dunne and Raby (1999), the design of Product X is an embodied critique on the consumer culture. You might perhaps hotlink; According to [Dunne and Raby (1999)](http://www.dunneandraby.co.uk/content/bydandr/13/0), the design of Product X is an embodied critique on the consumer culture.

Comment: @ xenon Will you be providing a bibliography? I would definitely include details of Dunne & Raby's work in that. Otherwise I suspect Kris' comment is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of providing this sort of oblique reference is to use *compare,* abbreviated to ***cf.***

> **cf.** *abbreviation*
>   compare with (used to refer a reader to another written work or another part of the same written work).
>
> Origin:
>   from Latin *confer* 'compare'
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cf.?q=cf.)

See also [Cornell University's guide](http://www.law.cornell.edu/citation/6-300.htm).

The first example of use I found using Google uses it to provide Bible references where the reader is directed to supporting text which is not directly quoted. This is the same as your use:

> The most common Greek word for “wrath” is *orge.* The term occurs 36 times in the New Testament (cf. Romans 1:18; 2:5). [Source](https://www.christiancourier.com/articles/1279-true-meaning-of-grace-the)

Thus your reference would be

> The design of product X is an embodied critique on the consumer culture (cf. Dunne & Raby, 1999)

You are not directly quoting, so your reference should not give that impression. *Cf.* provides the mechanism to show that you are basing a statement of your own on other evidence.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't cite anyone. Alternatively, you may add "as described above" or something similar.